# Search Kit Issues

Tags: searchkit

I truly appreciate the help I have been given with my various issues. I have applied the fixes in my test site and they work just fine however when I opened SearchKit in my production site to apply them there I now see this displayed

[image]

Joomla 4.4.1 , PHP 8.1 , Civi 5.67.1

I have to ask again , what the heck is causing this?

Thanks Coleman , this is what is being displayed in my browser console

[image]

Expanded Trace:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a javascript crash, which can be caused by a few different things. Could be a misconfiguration in Civi, or in Joomla, or in your theme or one of your extensions. First step is to open your browser console to see what the error message is & get as much info as you can about it & include it in your question.

Comment: I should have said that I have pasted the output from the browser console in my original post above

Comment: Ok, good start. Please click the little black triangle next to "Error" to open it up & see where it came from.

Comment: Thanks Coleman , pasted in above.

One comment I need to make is that all my environments sit on the same server but run as virtual containers. I have checked that the underlying software across the piece is the same and can't see any differences.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly that backtrace doesn't show anything I was hoping to see (anything to do with Civi or some other extension we could blame).

Comment: Thanks again Coleman , this is strange to say the least. I will do some more digging but I think the best thing I can actually do is to rebuild the whole site from scratch and hope that fixes the issue